# When creating loading up multiple pages at one time with View Pager 2, they all have the same content

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In this routine app, i'm trying to load info for multiple pages and create all pages at once. I succesfully used view pager to create seprate pages like this one at a time, but when I try to load the info with a forloop at one time, they all end up having the same content instead of the respective info. Should I just try using a timeout between loading each page?

This is the code:

```
//Get routine from intent
        userRoutine = (RoutineISO) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("routine");
        ArrayList<String> routineDays = userRoutine.getDays();
        //This foreach loop just goes through each day in the routine
        //and pull the data out of the respective maps
        //This is then used by the day adapter when building out the
        //fragment pages
        Log.i("DEBUG","Printing out days");
        for(String day: routineDays){
            this.dayExercises = userRoutine.getSplitDays().get(day);
            Log.i("DEBUG", dayExercises.toString());
            this.focusGroups = userRoutine.getMuscleGroups().get(day);
            this.dayTitle = day;
            NUM_PAGES++;
            pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            
        }
```

This is the code for the pager adapter i'm using

```
 private class DayAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
        private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
        private Context context;
        public DayAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
            super(fa);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            // Return a NEW fragment instance in createFragment(int).
            Fragment fragment = new DayFragmentISO();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("title", dayTitle);
            //Tells the fragment this is an existing day
            //so it knows to look for a focusList and dayExercises
            args.putBoolean("existing",true);
            args.putSerializable("focusList",focusGroups);
            args.putSerializable("dayExercises", dayExercises);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }


    }
```

Also note I have the NUMPages as private static int NUM_PAGES = 0; in my activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not iterating across a list of data items in the adapter, but setting a single data item and reading that single data item from the adapter.

An adapter iterates `Adapter::getSize()` times. Your override tells it to iterate over `NUM_PAGES` data items. When `notifyDataSetChanged` is called, it calls `createFragment` each iteration and executes that code to create one fragment.

The problem is structural--You need to make sure the dataset that the adapter observes is iterable.

As a side note--Calling `notifyDataSetChanged` for every item you add is generally a poor idea. The adapter will re-create every fragment, every time a new page is inserted.

Notice that `createFragment` provides a parameter, `int position`. Adapters (generally) take a `List<Object>` and create one item per `Object` in that list, for each index.

There's too little context provided to give you a strict solution, but ideally, you'll want to do something like the following:

1. Create a class to represent a page. It should contain members for all data necessary to construct an instance of the fragment.

```java
public class MyPageClass {

    // Maybe init fields here if they are required
    public MyPageClass(){} 

    private String dayTitle;
    private List<FocusGroup> focusGroups;
    private List<DayExercise> dayExercises;

    // Getters + Setters as needed, or any interface you want
    // < ... >

}
```

2. Modify your code to construct a list of page objects

```java
    //Get routine from intent
        userRoutine = (RoutineISO) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("routine");
        ArrayList<String> routineDays = userRoutine.getDays();

        // Define a private data member pages as an empty ArrayList--You probably want to
        // clear it here.
        this.pages = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String day: routineDays){
            // Building our page
            MyPageClass page = new MyPageClass();
            page.setDayExercises(userRoutine.getSplitDays().get(day));
            page.setFocusGroup(userRoutine.getMuscleGroups().get(day));
            page.setDayTitle(day);
            // Adding it to the list that pagerAdapter observes
            this.pages.add(page);
        }

        // Now we notify the adapter, once all of these changes have finished.
        // Consider using more specific methods, like notifyItemRangeInserted() etc
        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

3. Modify your adapter code to rely on this list.

```
private class DayAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
       private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
       private ArrayList<MyPageClass> pages; // This is our list of MyPageClass instances
       private Context context;

       public DayAdapter(FragmentActivity fa, ArrayList<MyPageClass> pages) {
           super(fa);
           this.pages = pages;
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
           // Return a NEW fragment instance in createFragment(int).
           Fragment fragment = new DayFragmentISO();

           Bundle args = new Bundle();
           args.putString("title", pages.get(position).getDayTitle());
           //Tells the fragment this is an existing day
           //so it knows to look for a focusList and dayExercises
           args.putBoolean("existing",true);
           args.putSerializable("focusList", pages.get(position).getFocusGroup()));
           args.putSerializable("dayExercises", pages.get(position).getDayExercises());
           fragment.setArguments(args);
           return fragment;
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           // This tells the adapter how many fragments to create.
           // We want one for each page, so we'll pass it the size of our data.
           return pages.size();
       }


   }
```

Comment: Oh, I see why it wasn't working now, this worked perfectly for my problem, thank you!